# Writing to kml file: How send kml string to kml file?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a project that draws on the map and generates kml as a string. I want to send this to a kml file via an ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: 'myurl.kml',
    data: kmlString,
    success() {
       //say it succeeded
    }
});
```

Because my kml data is nested inside quotes, like so,

```
'<xml.....</kml>'
```

the kml file complains that the syntax is incorrect due to the quotes (which is true).

I've thought of passing the data as a json object instead of a string, like this,

```
{'mapData': 'mykmldata'}
```

but the data is still encapsulated by quotes.

What is the best way to get my data to the kml file without quotes? Google maps API v3 doesn't seem to have a "string to kml" function anywhere, although I feel that would be the panacea in this case.

I noticed that the Google Earth API has a parseKml function, is that compatible with google maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third party KML parser [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) has a "parseKmlString" method, which will take valid KML from a string and parse it to create native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects.

Example: 
Take the KML from this file:
http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/MA_cities.kml

snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>Massachusetts Cities</name>
    <Folder>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Boston</name>
            <description>Boston is the capital of and largest city in Massachusetts.  The Boston Massacre and the Boston Tea Party occurred in Boston and led to the American Revolution.</description>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-71.05977300312775</longitude>
                <latitude>42.35843100531216</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>-2.107386233340164e-009</heading>
                <tilt>0</tilt>
                <range>34426.00143998101</range>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin9</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>-71.05977300312775,42.35843100531217,3.1482280535562</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Worcester</name>
            <description>Worcester is known as the &quot;Heart of the Commonwealth&quot; due to its location in central Massachusetts, thus, a heart is the official symbol of the city.</description>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-71.80229299737233</longitude>
                <latitude>42.2625930065606</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>1.76716070878667e-009</heading>
                <tilt>0</tilt>
                <range>17233.50055269895</range>
                <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
                <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin0</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>-71.80229299737233,42.26259300656061,145.2545892926215</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Paste it into the KML text box on this page:

http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html

It displays the markers from the KML.

Comment: Thanks. I also checked out the example you provided in the API comments. I can't seem to get my parser to add the string to its array of docs. I'm sure the string is proper kml. It's just a normal kml file with folders and polygons. This is how I'm doing it:  `var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map}); myParser.parseKmlString(kml);`  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the KML you are trying to use?

Comment: `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><kml><Document><Folder><name>A Folder</name><Placemark><name>A Polygon</name><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-111.68457224965096,40.25116680553771 -111.6846151649952,40.2490377737844 -111.67594626545906,40.24900501892662 -111.67581751942635,40.25237868600809 -111.68332770466805,40.25237868600809 -111.68332770466805,40.25237868600809 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark></Document></kml>`

Comment: And the parsekmlstring function converts the string to an object and pushes it to the array, right? I can't figure out why mine won't push. There must be something with my code. All you have to do is instantiate the geoXML parser and call the parseKmlString method, right?

Comment: After some work, I was able to get the kml string pushed to the parser's document array. However, I am not seeing a way to send my kml to a kml file as an object. I just need to "un-stringify" my kml string. Would that require an xml writer, or is there an easier way?